# Slider PHP, MYSQL and JS

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, slider

I'm working on a article website, and these articles are on a database it can be removed/added (CMS), it's all perfectly working, database and the slider. Now what i want to do is to integrate the articles on the slider. Here is my code witch it's not working, any tips? Thanks

JS:

```
sliderInt=1;
    sliderNext=2;
    $("#newsText > p#1").fadeIn(500);
    startSlider();


    function startSlider() {

        count = $("#newsText > p").size();
        loop = setInterval (function() {

            if (sliderNext>count) {

                sliderNext = 1;
                sliderInt = 1;
            }

        $("#newsText > p").fadeOut(500);
        $("#newsText > p#" + sliderNext).delay(500).fadeIn(500);
        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext ++;

        } ,7500);
    }


    function stopLoop() {

        window.clearInterval(loop);
    }


    function showSlide(id) {

        stopLoop();
            if (id>count) {

                id = 1;
          }
            else if (id<1) {

                id=count;
          }

        $("#newsText > p").fadeOut(500);
        $("#newsText > p#" + id).fadeIn(500);

        sliderInt = id;
        sliderNext = id + 1;
        startSlider();

    }

})
```

PHP/HTML:

```
    <?php
include_once('php/CMS/includes/connection.php');
include_once('php/CMS/includes/article.php');

$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();

?>

      //.......BODY......

<div id ="newsText">

            <?php 
            foreach ($articles as $article){
                for($articles=0; $articles <= count($articles); $articles++) {
                    $id = 1;
                    echo ("<p id =".$id++.">".$article['article_content']."</p>");
                }
            }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You havr any error message? It's seems you only start working with jQuery. Did you press F12 for viewing javascript errors in console?

I try you code at [http://jsfiddle.net/w9AHt/][jsfiddle] It's working fine at onready event, exept case when slide change from last to first.

Comment: I upedated my anwser, i added 'foreach...' on php... Now the slide just don't start... The slide woks fine with normal 'p' tags static.

Comment: I used id, because i can increment easly, eq() would be an alternative as well. thnx btw

Comment: Sometimes it's happend becose js code execute before html data are loaded/available did you try insert onready event?
 $(document).ready(fuction(){/*you code*/});

Comment: I updated my code... Now all the articles fade in all on the top of another and and don't loop. No error message it's just lack of logic from now, the prob is not on js, because if i wrie a few p tags (static) with numbered id's it works very well. Thanks